# Dynamic Items and jQuery Event Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am currently populating a list dynamically based on some web calls. When these calls return I use an HTML template to add another item to the list based on the call response. I also am trying to attach some events to these objects using jQuery, but when I generate the items it seems like only the last item generated has the appropriate events firing.

So here is the code:

The javascript generates the html string and the adds it to the list:

```
List.innerHTML += html;
```

The html is generated using moustache.js and renders properly, I set the id in the template before adding it.

The template has this form:

```
var template = '<li style="width:400px; height:100px" id="{{id}}"  ><img src="{{source}}" style="float:left"/>{{title}} <button id="{{id}}button">Delete</button></li>';
```

Where all the elements are replaced appropriately.

Then I try to attach a click event to the button and a double click event to the entire list object:

```
$('#' +id +'button').bind('click', function() {
       //SOME STUFF GOES HERE
     });

$('#' +id +'button').bind('dblclick', function() {
     //MORE STUFF GOES HERE
     });
```

Im not sure why the event wouldnt attach to each object, am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the elements in the DOM when you try to bind the events?

Comment: Are you binding those functions inside the loop which adds them or after it? Show some more code.

Comment: Im binding inside the loop that creates them, but the events are registered after I add the HTML to the list.

Comment: Seems to me the selector for the list is wrong. Shouldn't it be `$("#" + id)`?

Comment: Well that too, but the other event still isnt adding. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the selector? `button id="{{id}}button"` <-- `$('#' +id +'button')` as long as `id === {{id}}`. The question still doesn't make sense to me, do you append a `li` with each iteration and bind the events to it?

Comment: With each iteration of my loop, I create the html and append it to the li object, then I was trying to add events to the generated control

Comment: And the selector was wrong because the button id's all have id+button while the li object are only id

Comment: Oh yes, I guess I've misread the `entire list object` part. Thought the click/dblclick were to be attached to buttons only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DOM might not have been updated on the browser by the time you add the click handlers. You have a couple options:

1. Use delegated binding (using .on)
2. Attach the events before adding them to the DOM

Example 1:

```
$('body').on('click', '#' +id +'button', function () { /* foo */ });
```

Example 2:

```
$('#' +id +'button', myHtml).on('click', function () { /* foo */ });
List.append(myHtml);
```

Comment: I would also use delegation. If any specific data is needed when the click handler is called, you should use data-* attributes.

Comment: I do need specific data with these calls, how would I do this?

Comment: By adding data attributes to your template. Say you need a "name" attribute in your handler, add a `data-name={{name}}` to your template. Then in the click handler get that data back using `var name = $(this).data("name")`.